# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() breaks by timeout on SSL connection under Windows 7/Vista

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-7, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have an C# windows application (.Net 3.0 Framework) that makes a call to PHP web service using `HttpWebRequest`.

In **Win 7 & Vista**, if the call is made via non-SSL (i.e. `http://`), the code works fine.  When the call is changed to call the SSL(https:) version of the link, it times out at the `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()`.  This happens every time.

When this same application is run on a **Windows XP** machine it works fine with either the HTTP or the HTTPS url being used.

The code does have the accept all server certificates code in it.  Also, I have added [System.Net logging](http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html).  It writes out the log but because the packets are encrypted you really don't see much except for the Timeout abort statement.

I've also tried Fiddler but again with the encrypted packets, I don't see much.  BTW, when I try to use Fiddler2 to decrypt the app hangs so that has not been successful.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

I will add:

- I can telnet into the port
- I have tried running the app as Administrator
- I have tried the Win XP compatibility mode (trying anything)
- I have singled the connect code out into a simple stand-alone app

Comment: Can you paste the logile showing the timeout on pastebin.com?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error cropped up in a working C# application after migrating the website being accessed to a new server, and that indicated a server-side problem.  Indeed, we finally resolved this issue by setting the "ServerName" value in the Apache configuration file to match the domain name registered in the certificate.  (Another forum mentioned that setting "ServerAlias" would also work.)

More specifically, the httpd.conf file for the SSL site had the following in the VirtualHost section:

```
ServerName www.secure.mydomain.com
```

The certificate was registered to `secure.mydomain.com`, and the URL we were accessing was also `https://secure.mydomain.com/test.html`.

So simply changing the conf file to the following and restarting Apache did the trick:

```
ServerName secure.mydomain.com
```

The following would have also worked, most likely:

```
ServerName www.secure.mydomain.com
ServerAlias secure.mydomain.com
```

---

Here's some additional background information, for future reference:

The two errors we saw in the System.Net.trace.log were:

```
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [4316] Exception in the 
    Socket#18796293::Receive - A blocking operation was 
    interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
System.Net Error: 0 : [4316] Exception in the 
    HttpWebRequest#35191196:: - The operation has timed out
```

Here are all the things we tried which did not resolve the issue:

- installing intermediate certificates from the SSL certificate issuer into Apache (this is required)
- changing user agent in web request (no effect)
- changing server-side and client-side time-outs and memory limits (no effect)
- testing with a static page (no effect)
- testing with other https sites (they worked fine)
- adding the cert to the trusted certificates store (no effect)
- purchase and install a certificate from a different certificate issuer (no effect)
- compare virtual host .conf files from a known working server to the problem server (this led us to resolve the issue)

The https URL could be opened in Opera, IE8, and Firefox without any problems.  WGET for Windows complained about an invalid certificate, but then again, WGET is an old application and does not appear to trust as many certificates.

The C# client application worked under Windows XP, but not in Windows 7 or Windows Vista.  It appears that Windows 7 and Vista are more aggressive about validating the certificate. They do not provide an informative error message when it fails, and instead simply time out during the SSL handshake.

Comment: Thanks for posting the resolution to the problem Shailesh.  Hadn't had a chance to update it yet.

Comment: This was right on the money.  What a terribly misleading error message.

Comment: Thanks for this response, it solved what was a very perplexing problem for us. We had machines that were up-to-date with Windows Update whose .NET programs were timing out when contacting the web server. Machines that had not been updated since before (about) July 2012 were working fine. So there's a Windows update which modifies the behaviour sometime around this period. Fixing the `ServerName` value on the Apache web server solved the problem for us.

Comment: This answer saved my day.

Comment: I wonder, if there is a way to solve it on a client side? I use Proxy provider and I don't have access to proxy configurations...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the SSL certificate refers to a CRL which takes too long to fetch?

Comment: You can disable checking of CRLs. Set ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList=false. Also if you use wireshark you can see if the timeout is due to CRL or something else entirely. If you post your system.net log on pastebin I can also take a look.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback guys.  I appreciate it.  Shailesh (humbads) and I tracked it down to being a certificate setup issue on the server.  The answer is above.  Thanks again!